# Multiple line powershell command in JobDSL

Tags: powershell, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm tinkering with JobDSL and can't seem to find a way to run several powershell commands in one go. Example:

```
job('whatever'){
 steps{
  powershell("""$var = $env:mybuildvar
   cmdlet2 $var""")
 }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

it seems that """ """ works for batch, but not for powershell.
Also, if I try to use $var with escaping or without JobDSL fails with

> ERROR: (sandbox_CI_Dev, line 15) No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.powershell() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [$var =
>   $ENV:mybuildvar]

The error is reproducable on jobdsl playground (http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/), use following code (or anything similar to code above):

```
job('whatever') {
    steps{
        powershell("write-output $")
    }
}
```

also powershell('write-output test; write-output test') doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method name is `powerShell`, not `powershell`. See https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-steps-powerShell.

And Groovy interpolates double quoted strings, see [String interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation). You need to use single quotes to avoid the interpolation if you want to use the dollar sign (`$`), e.g. `'$var'`. Use triple single quotes for multiline strings.

```
job('whatever'){
  steps{
    powerShell('''$var = $env:mybuildvar
cmdlet2 $var''')
  }
}
```

Comment: omg, powerShell, that explains why it didn't work with ''' ''' in my tests... i swear to god I would never catch that capital S. Thanks, probably saved me a couple of days, if not weeks!